# Where's my tab completion and up-arrow behavior? (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, accounts

I'm new to Linux, trying Ubuntu 10.04, preconfigured by host.

When I log in (SSH) using the preconfigured account, the shell prompt is: user@hostname:~$

The up arrow scrolls through the list of recent shell commands, and tab-completion works as expected.

However, when I create an account and log in (SSH) using that account, the shell prompt is simply "$", and the up arrow just prints a control character (^[[A).

Can anyone tell me how to get my prompt, tab-completion, and up-arrow behavior set up? The fact that I'm getting control characters when I up-arrow makes me think that my account (or session) is in some mode I'm unfamiliar with.

I know there is tab-completion code stored in bashrc that I can uncomment, but that doesn't seem to have any effect, even after logging out and logging back in.

Am I in some strange mode when I SSH in with the new account, or are there just some session/account settings I need to set up, and can find information for anywhere on the Internet if I just knew what to look for?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My first guess is that the default shell is `sh` rather than Bash. Use `chsh` to change it. You will need to log out and log back in to make the change take effect.

Comment: edited /etc/passwd , changed to /bin/bash.. Thank you Dennis Williamson :)

Answer (score 8):

Other way is open /etc/passwd file and change the shell /bin/sh to /bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dennis Williamson the problem was the default shell. I was using Debian and my non-root user defaulted to sh.

```
chsh
/bin/bash
```

Re-logged in and problem solved.